# Access control of dynamically added user control from parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, user-controls

I have a Product.aspx page in which i have a `asp:panel`. I am adding a `UserControl` in it dynamically using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl(Programs/Test/Test.ascx);
    this.pnlLayoutDetails.Controls.Add(userControl);
    LayoutPanels = pnlLayoutDetails.Controls[1];
}
```

I have a button in Product.aspx page. I am hiding some `Panel`s from `UserControl` `onClick` of this button. Code is executing properly but when i see output it shows no effect (all controls are visible).

code for `button_click`

```
var pnlLayout = (Panel)LayoutPanels.FindControl("pnlLayout" + layout.LayoutID.ToString());
if (pnlLayout != null)
    pnlLayout.Visible = false;
```

**UPDATE:** If i remove ajax panel from aspx page then it works fine. But with ajax panel it creates problem. I am not able to figure it out. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you add the UC dynamically instead of declaratively?

Comment: yes it depends on usertype and there are different controls for different users

Comment: what is supposed to be inside LayoutPanels? userControl? way are you putting directly the control[1] are you shore its always the second one?

Comment: What kind of problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Please verify that you have set UpdatePanel.UpdateMode properly or not in aspx page. Also check if you have missed UpdatePanel.Update() in code behind. If possible please post your aspx side code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is `because you might not have panel in update panel section`.

try moving you panel to aspx page. it will solve your problem.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLayoutDetails" >
                    //dynamically added usercontrol
            </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then execute this it will work.

```
var pnlLayout = (Panel)LayoutPanels.FindControl("pnlLayout" + layout.LayoutID.ToString());
if (pnlLayout != null)
    pnlLayout.Visible = false;
```